# set title attribute in wp_get_attachment_image()

Tags: title, images

I am trying to use wp_get_attachment_image() and set a different title attribute from what is stored in the media library for that image.

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, 'large', false, array ('title' => 'My Custom Title'));
```

However I cannot get it to override the title attribute at all; I can override alt, id, class etc but not title.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a relatively fresh install I can't replicate the issue. When I post your code with my own image ID I get the `title="My Custom Title"` attribute.

It's important to note however that the "Title" of an image in the media library is *not* output as a `title` attribute in the standard output of `wp_get_attachment_image()`. The "Title" is just the name of the listing in the media library. WordPress does not output a title attribute automatically, I think because it's not considered a benefit for accessibility. By default it will only output the value of "Alt Text" as an `alt` attribute.

You should be able to set the attribute in `wp_get_attachment_image()` the way you have, however. If there is a title attribute being added without your intervention then a plugin or theme must be adding it with the [`wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) filter. This filter is run after your attributes are assigned, so if there is a value you cannot overwrite in the attributes argument, then this would explain why.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. Did a search in the project and found the filter had been added at some point. Thanks!